# Regex to block emails from spoofed domains

Tags: regex

I need to block emails which are from spoofed domains.I need to create a regex for that.

regex should match below email addresses

```
    *@test_control.com
    *@test.control.com
    *@test+control.com
    *@testcontrol
```

regex should not match the below email address which is a legitimate domain

***@testcontrol.int**

Comment: How did you try to achieve your goal? What is your question? Which part of this problem causes you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that * means "any email address with this domain":

```
.+@test.*control(?!\.int)
```

But if you want to match an email whose name is *literally* *, then

```
\*@test.*control(?!\.int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
\*@test[.+_]control(.com)?
```